# Running a python script using several computers (grid/cluster)

Tags: python, grid, webserver, cluster-computing

Is there a way to run my python script using several computers communicating through my web server? Willing to do a lot more research if someone can point me in the right direction, but I can't seem to find any useful info on this.

Comment: A **simple Google search** for *Python distributed computing* brings up the Python wiki sites about [ParallelProcessing](https://wiki.python.org/moin/ParallelProcessing) and [DistributedProgramming](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DistributedProgramming).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple script can't be automatically distributed, you need to break it into components that can run independently when given a part of the problem. These components run based on commands received from a library like PyMPI, or pull them from a queuing system like http://aws.amazon.com/sqs/

This also means you can't rely on having shared local memory. Any data that needs to be exchanged must be exchanged as part of the command, stored on a shared file system or placed in a database AWS Dynamo, Redis, ect.

There are a large number of links to more resources available at https://wiki.python.org/moin/ParallelProcessing under the Cluster Computing heading.